# SQL query optimization for selecting specific columns from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I'm trying to select all tables which have columns OWNERID or L1ID or L1, but not have any of the following columns, HID, DHID, SPHID, SPHID, LINKHID, NODEID and SITEID.

The following is my SQL query. It's taking a long time. Can you give me a better solution or optimize this query.

```
SELECT 
      TABLE_NAME 
   FROM 
      USER_TABLES
   WHERE 
         TABLE_NAME NOT IN (
            SELECT TABLE_NAME 
               FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
               WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('HID', 'DHID', 'SPHID', 'LINKID', 'NODEID', 'SITEID')
               GROUP BY TABLE_NAME 
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
      AND TABLE_NAME IN (
            SELECT TABLE_NAME 
               FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
               WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('OWNERID', 'L1ID', 'L1')
               GROUP BY TABLE_NAME 
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have already tried other solutions and they don't seem to workout for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not exist / exists instead.  As long as you don't need to select values from the secondary tables, this is much faster than IN and especially NOT IN.  Basic reason is that as soon as there is a match, the evaluation is done.

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TABLES
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select 1
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('HID', 'DHID', 'SPHID', 'LINKID', 'NODEID', 'SITEID')
  AND USER_TABLES.TABLE_NAME = USER_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
)
and EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('OWNERID', 'L1ID', 'L1')
  AND USER_TABLES.TABLE_NAME = USER_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
)
```

However, I am not totally sure what your COUNT(*) = 1 means.  Only one of OWNERID or L1ID or L1, but not say L1ID and L1 in the same table?

My code, as written will work if you only care if one or more of your condition columns are present, i.e. how I understood your question in English.  If you need only 1 of them to be present, different query is needed.

Comment: Yes only one of OWNERID or L1ID or L1 will be in a table. They are all the same but with different names in different tables. Same applies to HID, DHID,....SITEID

Comment: I get this error ORA-00904: "USER_TAB_COLUMNS"."TABLE_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Example: If table1 has L1 and OWNERID, table2 has L1 only. I reject table1 and accept table2

Comment: Awesome. My query took 153 seconds and yours takes just 4 secs. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  An IN/NOT IN clause that is using a subquery (i.e. not your lists of column names, those are OK as is) can always be replaced by an appropriate EXISTS/NOT EXISTS and those fly in comparison to IN/NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('OWNERID', 'L1ID', 'L1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME IN ('HID', 'DHID', 'SPHID', 'LINKID', 'NODEID', 'SITEID') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it did not work. It gives me tables which still has HID or the other columns which I don't want

Comment: @user3571754 . . . This should not give you tables that have HID as a column, unless the case of the column is an issue.  You might want to put in `upper(column_name)` throughout the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
With exclude AS (
  select TABLE_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('HID', 'DHID', 'SPHID', 'LINKID', 'NODEID', 'SITEID')
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
)
, preInclude AS (
  SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('OWNERID', 'L1ID', 'L1')
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
 ) 
, Include AS (
  SELECT preInclude.TABLE_NAME
  FROM preInclude
  LEFT JOIN exclude ON preIncude.TABLE_NAME = exclude.TABLE_NAME
  WHERE exclude.TABLE_NAME is NULL
)

SELECT * 
FROM Include
```